# PHP regexp to surround numbers with html tags in strings

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some strings they are combinations of numbers and letters both like:
`A555D1E` , `452AE`, now i want to set a different color for numbers and letters.

So I need to surround numbers in string with html tags like `span` or `b` and result should be like this:

html:

```
<div class="spec-text">A<span class="n">555</span>D<span class="n">1</span>E</div>
```

css:

```
spec-text{
    color:red;
}

spec-text .n{
    color:green;
}
```

if there is some function like:

```
function surroundNumbersByTag($string, $tag, $classes){
    // codes that return this string:
    // 'A<span class="n">555</span>D<span class="n">1</span>E'
}
```

is there anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function surroundNumbersByTag ($string, $tag, $classes)
{
    return preg_replace("~([0-9]+)~", "<$tag class='$classes'>$1</$tag>", $string);
}

echo surroundNumbersByTag('A555D1E', 'span', 'n');
```

Comment: `$classes` is not array

Comment: It's GREAT @gareth-parker